# Can you change the Text shown inside a select element?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, select

I'm working on a react app and am trying to have the dropdown options of a select element be more descriptive than what actually is shown as the selection, for example:

Selected: A

but when you click on the element for the dropdown it shows: 
A - Useful cause of this that the other 1
B - Useful cause of this that the other 2
C - Useful cause of this that the other 3

I had some scrappy attempts like having an additional hidden option with the short text with the same value as the descriptive one, but its selected attribute is set to true if the selectedState is equal its value, but that came along with some inconveniences

Comment: Could you share the code of what you have at the moment?
Have you been looking into using a package for this?

Comment: Why not have the long text as the actual content for the option and 'A' for its value?

Comment: @MrLister doing that still leaves the long text shown inside the select element

Comment: Another option would be to have the Select element show no text at all and only an arrow to select, while showing selection via state, tried tinkering with font-size etc. but haven't come to an elegant solution.

Comment: You could try CSS like `option:first-child::after {content: ' - Useful cause of this that the other';}`, but that doesn't seem to work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

From a user experience perspective this seems rather odd and ....just not good. I can't imagine a dropdown with some options where everytime I choose one of them it changes completely.

I guess it would better to implement something like a tooltip. You can try the easiest one by having a `title` attribute in each option. Doing this, when you hover over an option, the description of title appears.

For example

```html
<select title="Please select your car">
    <option title='Choose a car' value="All" >All</option>
    <option title='Great car' value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option title='Another Great car' value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option title='Yet Another Great car' value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option title='Ok that&#39s enough :P' value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```